# Como eu consigo votar nas respostas?

Tags: suporte

Como eu consigo votar nas respostas que me ajudaram a resolver meus problemas? Fala que eu preciso de 15 pontos.

Comment: O motivo pelo qual você não consegue votar sem pontos é para evitar que qualquer pessoa se registe e comece de logo a votar, facilitando a fraude nos votos. Não é que não seja possível na mesma fazer batota, mas assim já dificulta um pouco.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A sua pergunta não seria uma dúvida se você tivesse seguido os passos de iniciante da plataforma no primeiro email após o seu cadastro. Mas eu posso te ajudar.

Você ainda não pode votar nas perguntas nem nas respostas. Pra isso você deve ter 15 pontos de reputação e ainda tem 9 pontos. A única coisa que pode fazer por enquanto é fazer perguntas, aceitar a resposta de alguém como solução para seu problema ou dúvida (botão com um símbolo de OK que fica logo abaixo dos botões de votação), e responder a dúvida de outras pessoas.

Você ganha pontos de acordo com suas ações. Veja este link para saber como se ganha pontos:
https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation

E veja neste link o que você pode fazer a cada nível de reputação alcançado:
https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges